# How to insert multiple rows into SQL Server Parallel Data Warehouse table

Tags: sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I am on PDW AU5 with SQL Server 2012 servers.  I have an empty replicated table that I'm trying to load data into.  I'm only loading 2 records.  So, I'm doing:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.some_table
(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
(1, 'x', 'a'),
(2, 'y', 'b')
```

From the books online, this should work.  (It works on SMP.)  However, PDW throws an error stating: `Parse error at line: 4, column: x: Incorrect syntax near ','.`

The comma that this error is referring to is the one after the first tuple.
What am I doing wrong?  Is inserting multiple rows via INSERT INTO not allowed on AU5?

Comment: This should work! I have used this pattern many time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation on MSDN for `INSERT INTO` states that Parallel Data Warehous and Azure SQL Data Warehouse uses a different syntax for insertions compared to normal SQL Server which crucially does not support multiple `VALUES` tuples unfortunately: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

```
-- Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse
INSERT INTO [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name 
    [ ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]
    { 
      VALUES ( { NULL | expression } [ ,...n ] )
      | SELECT <select_criteria>
    }
    [ OPTION ( <query_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]
[;]
```

However note that it does support `INSERT INTO [...] SELECT [..]` syntax, so you could hack it like so:

```
INSERT INTO foo ( x, y, z )
SELECT 1, 'x', 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'y', 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'z', 'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'a', 'd' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'b', 'e'
```

(The last line doesn't have a `UNION ALL` expression)

Comment: I'm getting an `Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.` error

Comment: Oh, I got it, last row should go without `UNION ALL` and with `;` in the end

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh Thank you for the tip, I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using INSERT INTO and SELECT: If you have a very large number of rows to insert it can fail with Error:

```
Msg 102042, Level 16, State 1, Line 1    
The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization. Please simplify the query.
```

The only alternative I have found is to insert each row individually as follows:

```
create table #A (ID integer, CollA varchar(10),  CollB Varchar(50))

Insert into #A values (2176035,'ADM1','DIFFERENT TO OPS1 APP')    
Insert into #A values (5530921,'ADM7','DIFFERENT TO OPS1 APP')    
Insert into #A values (5034949,'ADM7','DIFFERENT TO OPS1 APP')    
Insert into #A values (3780563,'ADM4','DIFFERENT TO OPS1 APP')    
Insert into #A values (5215169,'ADM2','DIFFERENT TO OPS1 APP')
```